# В каком классе хранить строковые константы в приложении на MVVM?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

Пишу приложение "Погода" под Android на kotlin. Архитектура приложения - MVVM. Данные о погоде получаю с помощью API Яндекса. Есть dto-классы ForecastModel, и FactModel. В поле condition класса FactModel приходят данные с сервера о погодных условиях в строковом формате ("partly-cloudy", "continuous-heavy-rain" и т.д.) Хочу сделать локализацию этих строк на русском и английском языках.
Для этого сделал метод getConditionLocalized() и вынес строки в ресурсы. Но в итоге вместо строк он выдаёт в результате числа. Понимаю, что скорее всего и константы, и функция getConditionLocalized() должны находиться в другом классе и, скорее всего, их нужно вызывать методом resources.getString(R.string.....), который в этом классе недоступен. Только вопрос, в каком классе размещать всё это? В репозитории, вью-модели или в каком-то другом?
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это правильно реализовать согласно модели MVVM?

Код классов ForecastModel и FactModel:

````
import com.company.myweatherapp.R

const val CLEAR = "clear"
const val PARTLY_CLOUDY = "partly-cloudy"
const val CLOUDY = "cloudy"
const val OVERCAST = "overcast"
const val DRIZZLE = "drizzle"
const val LIGHT_RAIN = "light-rain"
const val RAIN = "rain"
const val MODERATE_RAIN = "moderate-rain"
const val HEAVY_RAIN = "heavy-rain"
const val CONTINUOUS_HEAVY_RAIN = "continuous-heavy-rain"
const val SHOWERS = "showers"
const val WET_SNOW = "wet-snow"
const val LIGHT_SNOW = "light-snow"
const val SNOW = "snow"
const val SNOW_SHOWERS = "snow-showers"
const val HAIL = "hail"
const val THUNDERSTORM = "thunderstorm"
const val THUNDERSTORM_WITH_RAIN = "thunderstorm-with-rain"
const val THUNDERSTORM_WITH_HAIL = "thunderstorm-with-hail"


data class ForecastModel(
    val fact: FactModel?,
    val geo_object: GeoObjectModel?
)

data class FactModel(
    val temp: Int,
    val icon: String,
    val condition: String
) {
    fun getConditionIcon(): String {
        return "https://yastatic.net/weather/i/icons/funky/dark/$icon.svg"
    }

    fun getConditionLocalized(): String {
        return when (condition) {
            CLEAR -> R.string.clear_conditions_text.toString()
            PARTLY_CLOUDY -> R.string.partly_cloudy_conditions_text.toString()
            CLOUDY -> R.string.cloudy_conditions_text.toString()
            OVERCAST -> R.string.overcast_conditions_text.toString()
            DRIZZLE -> R.string.drizzle_conditions_text.toString()
            LIGHT_RAIN -> R.string.light_rain_conditions_text.toString()
            RAIN -> R.string.rain_conditions_text.toString()
            MODERATE_RAIN -> R.string.moderate_rain_conditions_text.toString()
            HEAVY_RAIN -> R.string.heavy_rain_conditions_text.toString()
            CONTINUOUS_HEAVY_RAIN -> R.string.continuous_heavy_rain_conditions_text.toString()
            SHOWERS -> R.string.showers_conditions_text.toString()
            WET_SNOW -> R.string.wet_snow_conditions_text.toString()
            LIGHT_SNOW -> R.string.light_snow_conditions_text.toString()
            SNOW -> R.string.snow_conditions_text.toString()
            SNOW_SHOWERS -> R.string.snow_showers_conditions_text.toString()
            HAIL -> R.string.hail_conditions_text.toString()
            THUNDERSTORM -> R.string.thunderstorm_conditions_text.toString()
            THUNDERSTORM_WITH_RAIN -> R.string.thunderstorm_with_rain_conditions_text.toString()
            THUNDERSTORM_WITH_HAIL -> R.string.thunderstorm_with_hail_conditions_text.toString()
            else -> condition
        }
    }
}

data class GeoObjectModel(val locality: LocalityModel)

data class LocalityModel(val name: String)```
````

Comment: Возвращайте не сами строки, а их ResID. Кому надо получить строку, достанет Context и вытянет ее сам из ресурсов.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Возьму на вооружение, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getConditionLocalized()` и все остальное надо маппить в маппере. `Mapper` это такой класс который преобразовывает одну модель в другую и все. Ну и
правильно было бы завести какой нить энам - `ENUM` в котором перечислить всю погоду, и в маппере разруливать. В маппер понадобится что то типа контекст провайдера. Тут что то типа даггера поможет. Дата класс не для того что бы в нем была логика.
Примерно у вас должен быть что то типа такой схемы =
Получаете модели удаленные от сервера, маппер перемапливает их и делает все преобразования и на выходе получается уже другая модель с готовыми данными.(Что то типа `ModelRemote` ->`map` `ModelLocal` ->`map` -> `ModelUi` То есть моделей несколько слоев. как минимум.
MVVM здесь не причем. Тут посмотрите на Clean Architecture что бы понять. Вьюмодель это UI слой, туда уже все готовое должно приходить из слоя данных.
Кроме того у вас стринга приводится к виду `toString`  не зачем.

Comment: Где ж там стринга, Романыч? Там инта :)

Comment: А инжектить контекст в наше время без Даггера уже никак?

Comment: Да, не заметил, но в целом ответ , думаю, понятен. предоставлять зависимость да как угодно по сути

Comment: @Романыч Спасибо, теперь намного понятнее!